# VSTS multiple regions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, regions

How can I deploy VSTS in multiple regions where the data will be synced continuously?

We have development centers across the world and would like to migrate TFS to VSTS to achieve latency across the globe.
How can I make sure that I get VSTS deployed in multiple regions and sync them accordingly?
Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure that I get VSTS deployed in multiple regions and
>   sync them accordingly? Any pointers are appreciated.

What's that mean for "`deployed in multiple regions`" here?

If you mean manage source codes in version control, then you just need to add all the related users in your team project (Create team/group by region and set permission as needed). After that all the team members across the world can access the project in VSTS, then they can edit/modify and check in the changes...

If you mean build/release or deploy the project to different server/location by regions. Then you can [deploy and use the private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts) to build/release and deploy to the local network location in each region. Just create a CI/CD pipeline to trigger that.